# TypeError: a.mobile.datebox is undefined in backbone application

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a date field in my application. But when I load my app, I get "a.mobile.datebox" is undefined error at times (not everytime).
I am using

- backbone1.1,
- jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js,
- jqm-datebox-1.1.0.core.js,
- jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Any help is appreciated